# Which is more accurate glm or glmnet?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmnet

R glm and glmnet use different algorithms.

I notice non trivial differences between the estimated coefficients when I use both.

I am interested in when one is more accurate than another, and the time to solve/accuracy trade off.

Specifically I am referring to the case where one sets lambda=0 in glmnet s.t. it is estimating the same thing as glm.

Comment: You're asking about performance and accuracy differences when lambda=0, where the two should theoretically be identical. I think you should add that into your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Glmnet is for elastic net regression. This penalises the size of estimated coefficients (via a mix of L1 and L2 penalties). It tries to explain as much variance in the data through the model as possible while keeping the model coefficients small. I found these [slides](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/enet_talk.pdf) helpful to understand it.

Glm doesn't use a penalty term.

The effect, as I understand it, that with elastic net you may be accepting some bias in return for a reduction in the variance of the estimator. So which is best must depend on how you define 'best' in terms of bias and variance. (E.g. I know glmnet has advantages when you have many features compared to observations)

Comment: Well you'r just explaining what glmnet does - but the OP was referring to the situation when you set lambda=0 in glmnet, in which case the result should in principle return the same as a (nonpenalized) glm (save for some small numerical differences linked with the cyclical coordinate descent fitting method that is used in glmnet).