# Logistic regression in R - understanding function outputs

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, glmnet

I'm looking to gain more understanding on how to properly perform logistic regression using R.

I have a matrix x with 20 features (columns) and 1000 samples (rows) and a response vector y with values either 0 or 1.

The way I have fitted logistic regression is:

```
model <- cv.glmnet(x, y, type.measure='auc', alpha=1, family='binomial')
```

This outputs a list of values.

Then to check the performance of the model I use the predict function on unseen data (x2):

```
predicted  <- predict(model, s=model$lambda.min, newx=x2, type = "response")
```

Which returns a list of values for each of the samples between 0 and 1 corresponding to the probability of being each class. Right?

Am I taking the right steps? What other things should I be looking at? Should I be using lambda.min?

I think the next step is to find the cutoff point that maximises accuracy for the model.

I would also like to plot the resulting curve given my model's parameters, something like this. Or any other way of visualising / understanding what my final model is, what the parameters and regression coefficients are etc.

[image]

If anyone can recommend a good tutorial with detailed explanations of the outputs of each step and how to interpret and use them that would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Comment: For one, `cv.glmnet` is not logistic regression. See `?glm`, and `?binomial`, also UCLA IDRE has useful self didactic lit on logistic regression in R (stata and SAS).

Comment: What is cv.glmnet with family='binomial' then? I've seen it used on what they claimed was logistic regression

Comment: I will check out the literature recommended

Comment: This site discusses how to do cross-validation with logistic regression using glmnet https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html#log

Comment: Thank you @ToddBurus so was I doing logistic regression? Reading this makes me think I was, but AdamO claims I was not.

Comment: @agustin It doesn't look like pure logistic regression (they mention a penalty term). For that you're probably better using glm with `family=binomial(link='logit')`. I believe that would be the more desirable approach. Here's article showing how to use glm: https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/glm.html. You can do cross-validation in glm with `cv.glm`. Also, this post explains differences in glm and glmnet: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58167/which-is-more-accurate-glm-or-glmnet

Comment: Thanks will check them out!

Comment: with glmnet and parameter `family="binomial"` you do logistic regression, but with a lasso penalty term -- this means you're performing variable selection, too.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I wanted to do, at least initially as I had many variables and wanted to reduce this. I could always do the first step with glmnet, find a smaller set of relevant variables. Then fit logistic regression to the reduced sample with glm.